# $f : X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ satisfying $f(0) =0$ and $f(1) =1$ exist?

Tags: general-topology

For which subspace $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$  with the  usual topology  and with$\{0,1\} \subseteq X$ will a  continious  function $f : X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ satisfying $f(0) =0$ and $f(1) =1$  exist  ?

$a)$$ X=[0,1]$

$b)$$X=[-1,1]$

$c)$$X=\mathbb{R}$

$d)$$[0,1] ⊄X$

i was thinking about the  function $f(x) = x$ that is $f(0) =0$ and $f(1) =1$ and  i don't know  how  to tackle this  question

Any  hints/solution

thanks u

Comment: $f\colon X \to \{0,1\}, x\mapsto x$ is not well defined on the four choices of $X$. For example, in a) $f(\frac12)=\frac12 \notin \{0,1\}$.

Comment: @Babelfish thanks u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the image of a connected set by a continuous function is again connected.

Comment: thanks longa...